# jQuery - .load(load) having problem load content after another loaded content

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery load and then as soon as the content is loaded into the div i load another content from the new one. My problem is that the "prec3" wont load. How can I do? Probably using settimeout?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var filtralink = $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];                                      
var primaimmagine = $('.forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
var fotothumb = "http://site.com/photo/data/" + filtralink + "/thumbs" + primaimmagine;
fotothumbdarip =fotothumb;

$('body').prepend('<br /><div id="precunz" class="precunz" name="precunz"></div><div id="precduz" class="precduz" name="precduz"></div><div id="prectruz" class="prectruz" name="prectruz"></div>');

 $('div[align=center]:eq(1)').append('<br /><ul id="categories"><li><a href="#load">load</a></li><div class="dropdown"><ul><li><a href="#show">Show</a></li></ul></div></ul><div id="precun" class="precun" name="precun"></div><div id="precdu" class="precdu" name="precdu"></div>');

$(".precunz,.precduz,.prectruz").hide();    

var prec1 = $(".forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(previous)').attr('href');
prec1darip =prec1;

var prec1cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];

$(".precunz").load(prec1+" ol.floatcontainer");

$('#categories > div').hide();

var $listHeader = $('#categories > li');
$listHeader.live("click" ,function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#categories > div').toggle();

var prec2 = $(".precunz .forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(previous)').attr('href');
  prec2darip=prec2;
  var prec2cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];
prec2cat1splitdarip = prec2cat1split;
 var prec2immgran = $('.precunz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
  prec2immgrandarip = prec2immgran;
$(".precduz").load(prec2+" ol.floatcontainer"); 

/// This prec3 can't load     
var prec3 = $(".precduz .forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(previous)').attr('href');
prec3darip=prec3;
var prec3cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];
prec3cat1splitdarip = prec3cat1split;
var prec3immgran = $('.precduz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
prec3immgrandarip = prec3immgran;
$(".prectruz").load(prec3+" ol.floatcontainer");
});

$('#categories > div a').click(function() {
    $('#categories > div').hide();
    $(this).prependTo('#categories > li');
    $('#categories > li > a:eq(1)').prependTo('#categories > div > ul > li:empty');
    $listHeader = $('#categories > li');
var prec1immgran = $('.precunz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
var prec1th = "http://site.com/photo/data/" + prec1cat1split + "/thumbs" + prec1immgran;
$('.precun').append('<a href="' +prec1+ '"><img src="' +prec1th+ '" alt="" />');

var prec2immgran = $('.precduz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
prec2th = "http://site.com/photo/data/" + prec2cat1splitdarip + "/thumbs" + prec2immgran;
$('.precun').append('<a href="' +prec2darip+ '"><img src="' +prec2th+ '" alt="" /></a>');

/// this wont work because prec3 is not there
var prec3immgran = $('.prectruz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
var prec3th = "http://site.com/photo/data/" + prec3cat1splitdarip + "/thumbs" + prec3immgran;
$('.precun').append('<a href="' +prec3darip+ '"><img src="' +prec3th+ '" alt="" /></a>');

$('.precun').append('<a href="' +$(location).attr('href')+ '"><img src="' +fotothumbdarip+ '" alt="" />');
return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Dont you think you should accept your previous questions answers to get this one answered?

Comment: Other questions which you have asked on SO.

Comment: Yes i did once because it was the right answer for me :-). Could you please help me whit this .load() problem (and please forgive me for my English)?

Answer (score 0):

The load() function accepts an onComplete callback as an argument, so if you need to delay the prec3 load until after the prec2 load completes, you can do this:

```
var prec2 = $(".precunz .forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(previous)').attr('href');
prec2darip=prec2;
var prec2cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];
prec2cat1splitdarip = prec2cat1split;
var prec2immgran = $('.precunz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
prec2immgrandarip = prec2immgran;
$(".precduz").load(prec2+" ol.floatcontainer", function(){     
    var prec3 = $(".precduz .forumrow table").find('a').filter(':contains(previous)').attr('href');
    prec3darip=prec3;
    var prec3cat1split =  $('.blockhead a').filter('a[href^="http://site.com/photo/showgallery.php?cat="]').attr('href').split(/=/)[1];
    prec3cat1splitdarip = prec3cat1split;
    var prec3immgran = $('.precduz .forumrow table').find('img:first').attr('src').split(/medium/)[1];
    prec3immgrandarip = prec3immgran;
    $(".prectruz").load(prec3+" ol.floatcontainer");
});
```